# Spring MVC JSP not showing output properly

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I have the following in a JSP with Spring:

`<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,${item.imageDataBase64}"/>`

I have a debug statement in the `getImageDataBase64` method in the bean and the message gets printed in the Tomcat logs properly, the base 64 data is encoded there.

However, it does not display on my JSP. I have tried displaying the plain data in `<pre>` tags, but it is always blank.

If I just do `${item.imageData}` it displays the byte array data.

Here is the relevant Java code:

```
public String getImageDataBase64() {
    L.debug("Sending base 64 data: {}", org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
                                        .encodeBase64String(imageData));
    if (imageData != null) {
        return "";
    }
    return org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
           .encodeBase64String(imageData);
}

/**
* @return the imageData
*/
public byte[] getImageData() {
    return imageData;
}
```

Any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see your code works as expected and returns an empty string.

In your `getImageDataBase64` method try replacing this:

```
if (imageData != null) {
    return "";
}
```

with this:

```
if (imageData == null) {
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Good grief, rookie mistake.  Guess it was time to take a break